# How can I store token in cookie via fetch on frontend?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, fetch, token

I use React, typescript & the npm package universal-cookie

```js
// cookies.ts

import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

const cookies = new Cookies();

export const setCookie = (cookiename: string, value: string) => {
  cookies.set(cookiename, value, {
    path: "/",
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "strict",
  });
};

export const getCookie = (cookiename: string) => {
  return cookies.get(cookiename);
};

export const removeCookie = (cookiename: string) => {
  cookies.remove(cookiename, {
    path: "/",
  });
};
```

I added a console.log so I can see the token but nothing shows

```js
// loginUser.tsx

import { setCookie } from "@/lib/cookies";

export default async function loginFunction(body: Auth) {
  const url = "https://brainy-clothes-fish.cyclic.app/api/v1/auth/login";

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    const errorResponse = await response.json();
    throw new Error(
      `Request failed with status ${response.status}, ${errorResponse}`
    );
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  setCookie("jwtToken", data.token);
  console.log("jwtToken", data.token);

  return data;
}
```

I can't see the cookie in my Chrome dev > application > cookies

The backend sends the data correctly. I tested it with Postman.
Sample

```js
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NGExYWE2YzdmMDBlNGVlM2U5YjZjN2EiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODk5NDYyOTIsImV4cCI6MTY5MjUzODI5Mn0.-wDb7oknlCtIiCwFiNexrYrrVqVgXYq9FN_U8eFThmY"
}
```